# Launch android Apps From My Android Application

Tags: android

I want to list and launch the apps installed on my android device from my android application. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this code

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.package");
startActivity(intent );
```